# Android SQLiteDatabase returning null (blank) rows

Tags: android

been pulling my hair out with an app I am trying to build. I have tried so many different things, books, ways, youtube tutorials I have lost count! I am building a simple app which shows pictures of aircraft then the user clicks to add it to a learnt list (verified that is working by using toast instead of listview)  then clicks another button to view this list.

I have the app returning the correct number of rows but they are all blank! From what I have read this means the rows are null but I can't for the life of me figure what is wrong! I would be forever in the debt of whoever can help :)

Thanks! Here's the code...

(database helper/adapter)

```
    package com.atcapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseAdapter {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG = "DatabaseAdapter";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LearntListdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "AircraftTable";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table AircraftTable (_id integer primary key         autoincrement, "
        + "name text not null);";

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DatabaseAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + "which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AircraftNames");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

// ---opens the database---
public DatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// ---closes the database---
public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
}

// ---insert an aircraft into the database---
public long insertAircraft(String name) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// ---retrieves all the list---
public Cursor getAllAircraft() {

    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {"_id", "name"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    return c;
}
```

}

(List Activity)

```
    package com.atcapp;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class DataView extends ListActivity {

private DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.aircraftlist);

    mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);

    mDbHelper.open();
    fillData();

}

private void fillData(){
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.getAllAircraft();

    startManagingCursor(c);



    String[] from = new String[] {DatabaseAdapter.KEY_ROWID, DatabaseAdapter.KEY_NAME};
    int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.list};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myList =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, c, from, to);
    setListAdapter(myList);

}
```

}

Comment: If my answer helped you out, do us all a favor and mark it as the accepted answer (click on the little check mark next to it).  That way it doesn't show up on the unanswered list and everyone knows your issue has been resolved and they can skip over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply textview ids in your to array.  You need to be mapping data from the cursor to views in the adapter.

Look in your list_row layout and use the textview id from there.

Comment: Hi Barak, thanks for the quick reply. I have edited the array as such:

String[] from = new String[] {c.toString()};
  int[] to = new int[] {R.id.listrow};

And now I am getting this error:

4-11 22:25:46.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1601): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.atcapp/com.atcapp.DataView}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40558908' does not exist

I have tried cleaning/rebuilding the code with no effect. Thanks!

Comment: No no no.  Your from array was fine.  You need to change your to array.  int[] to =new int[] {R.id.yourtextview}… where youtextview is actually the textview defined in the R.layout.list_row layout you are using.

Comment: Perfect thanks so much. For reference the final code was: 

String[] from = new String[] {DatabaseAdapter.KEY_NAME};
  int[] to = new int[] {R.id.listrow};

All working, Barak is my hero :)